# Test event handler on TextButton

Tags: java, gwt, junit

I am trying to write unit test the custom handler added to the `TextButton` via `addSelectHandler`.

I am adding the event handler as

```
public class TestClass {
    public void add(TextButton button) {
        button.addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
                System.out.println("This is called");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now in the test, I am trying to do the following

```
@Test
    public void test() {
        TextButton textButton = new TextButton();
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass(); 
        testClass.add(textButton);
        textButton.fireEvent(new SelectEvent());
    }
```

However, the log is never printed. I am not sure what is wrong here.
Can somebody help me here?

Comment: I'm guessing that fireEvent is an asynchronous call? Possible that the test is finishing before the event gets handled

Answer (score 0):

You possibly need to set `delayTestFinish(500);`

This makes your GWT test case asynchronous.

See "Asynchronous Testing" on http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideTesting.html